# How to find maximum occurring element in a map? {elixir}

Tags: data-structures, elixir

So I have a map from which I'm trying to find the maximum occurring element for a key.

This is what I'm trying to do:-

Input

```
iex(1)> items = [%{name: 'soap', price: 50, quantity: 3}, %{name: 'pen', price: 10, quantity: 2}, %{name: 'pen', price: 14, quantity: 6}]
```

Output

```
    [
  %{name: 'soap', price: 50, quantity: 3},
  %{name: 'pen', price: 10, quantity: 2},
  %{name: 'pen', price: 14, quantity: 6}
    ]
```

Now I've grouped together similar element using group_by function

Input

```
iex(2)> items |> Enum.group_by(fn %{name: name } -> {name} end, fn %{quantity: quantity } -> {quantity} end )
```

Output

```
%{{'pen'} => [{2}, {6}], {'soap'} => [{3}]}
```

Now what I'm trying to find is

1. how many items occur for "pen" and "soap" or what if it gives me maximum value occurs in a particular key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after grouping by you want to reduce so you can create another `Map` and fill it

```
items 
|> Enum.group_by(&(&1.name), &(&1.quantity))
|> Enum.reduce(%{} , fn ({name, quantities}, acc) -> Map.put(acc, name, Enum.max(quantities)) end )
```

result is

```
%{'pen' => 6, 'soap' => 3}
```

Comment: Can we only group two items together? Not three or four?

Comment: you know that group by is just a reduce so you can make anything with reduce
https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.9.2/lib/elixir/lib/enum.ex#L1123